# What's a clean way of putting this big output into a dictionary that I can to get values out of? Python 3, student learning

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been extensively Googling and trying methods to solve this but I've come up lost and tired. I've got output that looks like this after I clean it up:

[image]

I want to break each row into a dictionary and have a key made for each column with the corresponding value assigned to the key that fits with the column. In the end, I want to be able to query for an attribute name and retrieve the value from a column specified.

E.g. `print(attribute_x + column_x + ": " + value)`

Definitely not the easiest problem in the world to start out with as a beginner in programming but not the hardest either I feel.

So I am wondering what would proper pseudo code or basic Python code look like for this?

I've yet to come across an example similar to this that isn't some CSV import.

Just messing around with code, I've been able to get the key names assigned to their own variable but I have failed to get the list to convert to a basic dictionary using methods like dic = dict.fromkeys(keys, None)

This is my code so far:

```
str = """
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   125   125   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       220
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       752
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       219
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       32062
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   193   193   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 5/52)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0"""

temp = [ ]

temp=str.split(" ")

for i in temp:
    x = [str for str in temp if str]
    y = [w.replace('\n', '') for w in x]

print(" ")

keys = (y[0:10])
values = ('') #????

#Print stuff
print("Print the column names:")
print(keys)
```

I briefly looked into the Python CSV modules as this output seems like it could be converted easily into a file like that where I could call corresponding cells based on their column but I wasn't able to make headway there.

Thank you for all you do, StackOverflow users.

Comment: have you tried look on panda lib?

Comment: Is that data guaranteed to be fixed-width? Then it's pretty trivial to break apart the rows at specific indices. If the data is at least guaranteed to never contain spaces, it's also trivial to break apart the rows at any space. Failing even that, if at least the column headers are guaranteed to not contain spaces and always align with the data columns, you could detect the spaces in the headers and their indices and use those to split the individual rows.

Comment: @itai I haven't, I'll take a look!

Comment: @IanSmith i think it will suit your needs perfectly tell me if it helped

Comment: @deceze thank you for the edit. I don't think the data is guaranteed to be fixed with. I'm gathering it from smartctl by having python execute 'smartctl -A C:

The entire output then gets decoded from a byte object and put into a string after that.

The command that creates this output, is there a way where I can check if it has columns I can reference in Python, similar to how you can awk {print $4} to print the 4th column on some bash output

Answer (score 0):

Since you know your header and that items will be separated by whitespace, you can build each row dictionary using `zip`. `zip` takes n iterables and returns a list of tuples with the N values at index 0, the N values at index 1, etc... across all N iterables (in our case N is 2).

That works out nicely because a dictionary can be constructed in exactly that manner (as a list of (key, value) tuples.

```
HEADERS = ('ID#', 'ATTRIBUTE_NAME', 'FLAG', 'VALUE', 'WORST', 'THRESH', 'TYPE', 'UPDATED', 'WHEN_FAILED', 'RAW_VALUE')

string = """
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      
UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   100   100   062    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   125   125   033    Pre-fail  Always       -       2
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       220
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   005    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   100   100   040    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       752
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       219
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   097   097   000    Old_age   Always       -       32062
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   193   193   000    Old_age   Always       -       31 (Min/Max 5/52)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x000a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0"""

data = []

for line in string.split('\n')[1:]:
    row = dict(zip(HEADERS, line.split(' ')))
    data.append(row)

for item in data:
    for key, value in item.items():
        print(key, value)
```

Comment: Thank you, why is it that the RAW_VALUES get lost in the data object when printing a row from it?